# How to get a reference to the layout from within a custom TextView

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

This is probably an easy question to answer, but searches were just turning up things like inflating and xml layouts, which isn't what I want.

I have a custom TextView that I want to draw a cursor on. (I can't use an EditText.) In order to draw the line, I need to calculate various coordinates from the character offset that the cursor should be at. I tried the following as a method of the custom TextView:

```
public void setCursorLocation(int characterOffset) {

    Layout layout = this.getLayout();

    int line = layout.getLineForOffset(characterOffset);
    mCursorX = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(characterOffset);
    mCursorBaseY = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
    mCursorBottomY = layout.getLineBottom(line);
    mCursorAscentY = layout.getLineAscent(line);
}
```

However, the layout is null. I even tried passing in the TextView as a parameter but the layout was still null. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void setCursorLocation(View view, int characterOffset) {

    Layout layout = ((TextView) view).getLayout();

    ...
}
```

**Update**

I changed it to the following

```
public void setCursorLocation(Layout layout, int characterOffset) {
```

but even that layout was null. Then I looked at where I was calling it from in the main activity:

```
inputWindow.setText(displayText);
inputWindow.setCursorLocation(inputWindow.getLayout(), glyphCurosrPosition);
```

Watching the expression `inputWindow.getLayout()` was fine until `setText` was called and then all of a sudden it became null. I guess that is because it invalidated itself. How/when do I draw the cursor then? My guess is to post a runnable maybe. **Update 2** Yes, see below.

Comment: try to get the parent of the view, getParent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution finally worked for me.

From the main activity:

```
inputWindow.setText(displayText);
inputWindow.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        inputWindow.setCursorLocation(glyphCursorPosition);
    }

});
```

In the custom TextView:

```
public void setCursorLocation(int characterOffset) {

    Layout layout = this.getLayout();

    int line = layout.getLineForOffset(characterOffset);
    mCursorX = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(characterOffset);
    mCursorBaseY = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
    mCursorBottomY = layout.getLineBottom(line);
    mCursorAscentY = layout.getLineAscent(line);

    this.invalidate();
}
```

The downside is that there is a slight time lag before the cursor updates itself.